# When can uncountable nouns be countable?

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I have a question about uncountable nouns that are used as countable in certain situations.

When it comes to some uncountable nouns such as *fruit*, *cake*, *coffee* etc., I have found out that they can be countable if they indicate specific items.

Here's an example.

> 1. I love chocolate **cake**. → The term *cake* is treated as a singular noun because here, *cake* is a general term.
> 2. I need **a cake** please. → Here, *a cake* means one of the cakes displayed in the bakery where I am visiting. Here, *cake* means the ‘whole’ cake.
> 3. I need **a piece of** cake. (at a coffee shop) → Here, *a piece of cake* means a part of the whole cake.

Usually, if we say,

> "I'd like some cakes"

it means I would like some pieces of cake, not the whole ones. In fact, my grammar book, *Grammar In Use* by Raymond Murphy, explains this.  It says: “When people say ‘some cakes’, it usually means ‘some pieces of cake’, not the whole ones.”

If this rule is correct, can I apply this rule to other uncountable nouns listed above?

Here are some other examples:

1. I love fruit as a dessert. (compared with *sweets*).
   I sell fruit in the market. (compared with *vegetables*)
   I am now eating **some fruits**. (some apples and bananas)
2. I like to drink coffee in the morning. (compared with *tea*)
   May I have **one coffee** please?
   I need **one** Americano. (at Starbucks)
3. I like fish. (compared with *meat*)
   Look at those **fishes** in the fish bowl.
   There are **several** gold fishes!
   I need **one salmon** and **two tunas**.

However, some uncountable nouns are always uncountable as far as I can see.

For example,

4. I love to eat cheese when drinking wine.
   I came here to buy **some** cheese. → in this case, even though I indicate some specific kinds of cheese or one kind of cheese, I still say ‘cheese’, right? I shouldn't say *a cheese*, or *a few cheeses*. Am I correct?
5. I love meat.
   May I have **some** beef and pork?
   **Some pounds of** beef, **a pack of** pork... → Here, I can't say “I need those beefs and porks”, can I?
6. I usually put **milk** in my coffee.
   I need **two cartons of** milk. → I can't say “I need two milks” unlike “two coffees", can I?
   I need **one** vanilla-flavored milk and **one** strawberry milk.--> In this case, though, I kind of feel that I can count them because it states a more specific kind of milk.

Comment: I don't know what your question is.  You say, "If this rule is correct, can I apply this rule to other uncountable nouns listed above?", but I don't see a rule.  But, aside from that, "Look at those fishes in the fish bowl" is wrong.  This is not a countable/uncountable issue; "fish" is countable here, but the plural of "fish" is "fish": "There are three fish in the bowl."   There are a few countable nouns whose plural is the same as the singular; e.g., [deer](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/188578/26083) and sheep.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. You need to be more specific about your question. Please read the linked related question and see if it answers your question. [Are there any simple rules for choosing the definite vs. indefinite (vs. none) article?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a). Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: To me, "Some cakes" means "some whole cakes", not "some pieces of cake".  Also i disagree that "coffee" is uncountable - i would always so "So, that's two teas and three coffees?" for example.

Comment: *Grammar In Use* by Raymond Murphy is usually spot on with its explanations. I don't have a copy with me, but the rule you cite *does* seem to be wide off the mark (incorrect). Could you double check to see if Murphy actually states this?

Comment: @MaxWilliams *coffee* is uncountable in simple requests, e.g. "How much coffee do you need?"

Comment: @Mari-LouA that's true.  I suppose that highlights the ambiguity of the word  "coffee", which can mean the product (ground, beans, instant etc) OR a **cup** of coffee.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Hello, thank you so much for your answer. I am actually reading the book, grammar in use again, and I was wrong. Some cakes mean some whole cakes.  But, it says, if it is some cake, which is singular, it means a piece of cake, not the whole cake. I was confused between some cakes (which means some whole cakes) and some cake (which means a piece of cake). Is it really true though, if some cake means a piece of cake?

Comment: @ Max Williams Thank you for your clarification.  In fact, I learned at school that coffee is uncountable, and I always need to use a cup of, a mug of, xx pounds of...  in front of the word, coffee in order to count it. However, I frequently heard people using coffees, lattes, cappucinos, expressos etc. while placing an order at coffee shops when I stayed in the US if I am not wrong.  And I thought if we talk about coffee in general, it is uncountable.  But if we indicate individual servings, it could be countable.  Did I understand your explanation correctly?

Comment: Yes, "some cake" could refer to a "portion" or a "slice" of cake, not the whole cake. But if we wanted to buy two birthday cakes, then we'd ask for "two cakes".  When coffee is unquantifiable e.g., the amount of coffee  in a coffee pot, then it's "some coffee", but if we can count the vessel in which it is served in then "two coffees (i.e. two cups of coffee)" is perfectly fine. DeadRat's answer is very complete, and is probably better suited to an advanced or proficiency level of English.

Comment: Related: **1**. [Why is liquid a countable noun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264393/why-is-liquid-a-countable-noun?lq=1) **2**. [Possible “rule” for uncountable nouns](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270469/possible-rule-for-uncountable-nouns?rq=1) **3**. [Why is bread uncountable? How do you describe the “three breads” in the picture?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120666/why-is-bread-uncountable-how-do-you-describe-the-three-breads-in-the-picture?rq=1)

Comment: Here are another two questions: **4**. [Can I use the word “milks” when discussing KINDS of milk](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111357/can-i-use-the-word-milks-when-discussing-kinds-of-milk) and personally, my favourite :) **5**  [Why is “toast” uncountable?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286613/why-is-toast-uncountable)

Answer (score 6):

Your search for a rule is admirable, but alas! doomed to failure.

- The plural of *fish* is *fish*.  Unless you're differentiating between species:

> The smaller **fishes** are more affected by ocean warming than the larger.

Or if you are a mafioso, in which case you say

> Vinnie sleeps with the **fishes**.

Of if you're a theologian discussing the miracle of

> the loaves and **fishes**.

Different species form plurals in unpredictable ways.  Both *tuna* and *salmon* are their own plurals.  Species that end in *-ing*, like the *ling* form their plurals by adding a final *s*, except for *grayling* and *herring*.  You just have to look it up [here](http://fisheries.org/docs/pub_style18.pdf).  However, if the fish name is the name of a special at your restaurant, you might hear a waitress call out

> I need two salmons and three tunas!

She means two orders of the salmon dish and three of the tuna dish.

No matter how many you have in a bowl, you only have *fish*, never fishes.

- *Cakes* is the plural of cake.  It never means pieces of cake:

  > Some cakes have frosting; others have icing.
- The plural of *fruit* is *fruits*, but only when you're talking about different varieties:

  > Some **fruits** -- bananas, apples, kiwis -- are good for you.  The rest are not.
  >   You always eat some **fruit**.
- Drinks are the typical nonountable nouns, except when you're talking about varieties or individual servings:

> Whiskeys are either blended or single-malt.
>   Give me two whiskeys, two scotches, two beers.

*Waters* has an additional plural as the naturally occurring water in a location, so during your vacation, you

> take the **waters** at the spa at the hot springs

- *Cheese* follows the variety rule.  If you have three **cheeses** on your cheese plate, then you have three different types of cheese, even when you have six pieces of cheese total.  Same with *milk*:

> I make three different nut **milks** in my blender -- walnut, hazelnut, and almond.

The plural of *beef* is **beeves**, but it's only used to describe individual animals, meat-on-the-hoof, so to speak.

Comment: Good thorough answer.